# Objective-C header file not recognizing custom object as a type

Tags: objective-c, import, compiler-errors

I'm working on a game for iPad using cocos2d which involves a board filled with different types of tiles. I've created a custom class called `Tile` as a general template for tiles and a few subclasses of `Tile` which have different properties and methods. I've also created a class called `Board` which, among other things, keeps track of the locations of all the tiles using a special coordinate system.

For some reason, in the `Board` class, the compiler doesn't seem to be recognizing `Tile` as a type of object, even though I've added `#import "Tile.h"` at the top of the file.

Here's the relevant code (just ask if there's other parts of the code you want to see):

**Tile.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Board.h"

@interface Tile : NSObject

-(void) updateNeighbors;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite* sprite;
@property (assign) CGPoint coords;
@property (assign) CGPoint positionInPoints;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *neighbors;

@end
```

**Board.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Tile.h"

@interface Board : NSObject

+(Board*)sharedBoard;

- (void) putTile: (Tile*) tile AtIndex: (CGPoint) index; //<-- error here!
- (void) replaceTileAtIndex: (CGPoint) index1 WithTileAtIndex: (CGPoint) index2;
- (Tile*) tileAtIndex: (CGPoint) index; //<-- error here!
- (void) populate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tiles;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *type;
@property (assign) CGPoint size;

@end
```

This code will not even build and I'm getting the following error where indicated:

> Expected '(' before 'Tile'

If I change the type from `(Tile*)` to `(NSObject*)`, it fixes the error, which leads me to believe that `Tile` is not being recognized as a type of object.

I've searched via Google and this site and cannot figure out why this is happening.

---

### Update

Dumb mistake; easy to fix.

As you all have pointed out the problem is that the two header files are importing each other, which is not allowed. For now, I've fixed the problem by moving the #import "Board.h" statement to Tile.m, since it isn't needed in the header file. Later on, if I decide to use Board in the Tile.h file I will use forward referencing (@class Board;), as a few of you suggested.

Thanks again!

Comment: Hav you tried adding a forward declaration of Tile (aka `@class Tile;`) at the top of Board.h?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is a classic problem with headers importing headers. You have a circle here: Tile.h is importing Board.h, which imports Tile.h. This confuses the compiler -- it gets stuck in a loop.

You solve this by not importing headers into headers. You still need to let the compiler know about `Tile`, however. In Board.h, make a ["forward declaration"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF124) of the class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@class Tile;    // Dear compiler, 
                // Tile is a class that I will need to refer 
                // to in this file. Please consider it to be a 
                // type; I promise it'll be defined at runtime. 
                // Sincerely, stephenalexbrowne

@interface Board : NSObject
//etc.
```

This assures the compiler that there is a class called `Tile` that will exist at runtime; you can then refer to that name in the remainder of your header. In your implementation for `Board`, you import Tile.h. That will let the compiler see the methods and properties associated with the `Tile` class where they are needed.

Likewise, move the `#import "Board.h"` into Tile.m. Since you aren't referring to the `Board` class in Tile.h, you don't need to make a forward declaration.

In general, it is best to import your class headers only into the implementation files where they are needed. Framework headers, since they will never cause a cycle with your code, can and -- because you need to refer to many of the classes declared in them -- should be imported into your headers.

Comment: So should one always use @class definitions in headers and include the actual header files in the implementation? Or should one only resort to this technique when a circular reference becomes a problem?

Comment: @Schrockwell: My personal practice, and what I've heard recommended by persons to whom I think it good to listen, is to _always_ use forward declarations in headers. The compiler only needs to see the header when you're trying to send messages to the class, to check whether the methods/properties are actually declared. Since that doesn't happen in another class's header file, `@class Something;` is sufficient.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I just spent a bunch of time tracking down a circular reference with some headers, so I can see how this helps.

Comment: On a somewhat related note, should class delegates (protocols) be defined in separate header files, or is it better practice to include them in the class header alongside the class definition they're relevant to?

Comment: @Schrockwell: A good question that I don't really have the answer to. I'd probably make the decision based on the complexity of the two; more complex means less readable if they're jammed in the same file. Might be worth posting a question about that, although you'd have to be careful to make it specific and not too subjective (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114313/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16599 for warnings about that).

Comment: // Dear compiler, 
                // Tile is a class that I will need to refer 
                // to in this file. Please consider it to be a 
                // type; I promise it'll be defined at runtime. 
                // Sincerely,    ------- Josh is really a good teacher!

Answer (score 6):

Two files cannot import each other. You need to move the import directives to the implementation files, and instead just *forward-declare* the classes in the headers (e.g. `@class Tile;` in Board.h).

The reason circular imports don't work is because `#import` literally includes the text from the imported file in-place. But it also ensures that the text from a file will only be included once, in order to avoid duplicate declarations. So when Tile.h says that the text from Board.h needs to go before it, and Board.h says the text from Tile.h needs to go before it, there's literally nothing the compiler can do — one of them needs to go first, and that file is going to complain because it was expecting the other one to already be there.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the problem, but what happens if you remove the "#import "Board.h"" from the Tile.h file.  You might have a problem with circular referencing