# xcode unknown type name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I got code like this:

Match.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "player.h"

@interface Match : NSObject
{
    Player *firstPlayer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Player *firstPlayer;

@end
```

Player.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "game.h"
@interface Player : NSObject
{
}

- (Player *) init;

//- (NSInteger)numberOfPoints;
//- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *surname;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger *player_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *notes;

@end
```

Game.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "match.h"
#import "player.h"

@interface Game : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *matches;
    NSMutableArray *players;
    NSString *name;
}

-(Game *) init;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *matches;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *players;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

@end
```

Xcode won't compile my project and show me error unknown type 'Player' in Match.h when I declare *firstPlayer.

I tried cleaning project, rebuilding it but without any result...

Comment: You have a cycle in your imports: Match.h imports Player.h imports Game.h imports Match.h. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7896440/557219).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C header file not recognizing custom object as a type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7896440/557219)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The normal way to solve this cycles is to forward declare classes:

In Match.h:

```
@class Player;
@interface Match ...
    Player * firstPlayer;
```

and do `#import "Player.h` only in Match.m, `not` in Match.h

Same for the other two .h files.

Comment: thanks a lot  even some times small issues take to much time to solve it is may be of losing memory power working in software field..

Comment: Cheers! Been looking for this solution for a while now. +1