# Unknown type name

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

My .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "GameData.h"
#import "PROBattleScene.h"

@interface PROBattleAI : NSObject {
    BattleType type;
    PROBattleScene *scene;
}

-(id)initWithType:(BattleType)_type andBattleInformation:(NSMutableDictionary*)_information andScene:(PROBattleScene*)_scene;
-(void)dealloc;
@end
```

But on the line `PROBattleScene *scene;` I get the unknown type name error from Xcode.

I tried the answer here: [xcode unknown type name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897268/xcode-unknown-type-name) but I am already doing that (and doesn't work).

Why is that happening? I am already importing my `PROBattleScene.h` file, why isn't it being recognized?

**EDIT**: And the contents of `PROBattleScene.h` as requested:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "GameData.h"
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"

#import "PROBattleBackground.h"
#import "PROBattleAI.h"

@interface PROBattleScene : CCLayer {
    NSMutableDictionary *battleInformation;
    NSMutableArray *localPlayerPartyData;

    PROBattleBackground *background;

    CCNode *base;

    PROBattleAI *enemyAI;
}
+(CCScene*)scene;
-(id)init;
-(void)loadBattleInformation;
-(void)loadBGM;
-(void)loadBackground;
-(void)loadBase;
-(void)loadEnemyAI;
-(void)beginBattle;

@end
```

Comment: Show us the contents of `PROBattleScene.h` as well please.

Comment: What's *in* your `PROBattleScene.h` file?

Comment: And you are defining a type named `PROBattleScene` (with exactly this spelling/uppercase/lowercase) in your file "PROBattleScene.h"?

Comment: Okay, there is `PROBattleScene.h` now.

Comment: Declare @class PROBattleScene and remove its header from .h file and import it in .m file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a circular dependency.  PROBattleAI imports PROBattleScene which imports PROBattleAI which imports PROBattleScene <del>< zomg infinite loop ></del>

Use `@class PROBattleWhatever` in your headers as much as possible.  Only import headers for protocol definitions or superclasses.

**EDIT** Ok, the above wording was totally bad...and misleading.  Here is what (I believe) happens in detail.  Your PROBattleAI imports PROBattleScene, which then imports PROBattleAI, which then imports PROBattleScene for a second time (all before it gets to any of the code in either file).  The import will ignore PROBattleScene this time because it has already been imported and you will get the undefined type error since the file was skipped.

Comment: `#import` prevents this loop, it is `#include` which creates this infinite inclusion loop. check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439662/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-include-in-objective-c

Comment: @samfisher #import prevents it from being imported more than once (like C++ #ifndef logic) but it doesn't work well against files the #import each other.

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't see that coming.

Comment: @samfisher I will admit my poor wording though, see my updated answer :).