# How to get the parentViewController in childViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, childviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I have a main `UIViewController` and named `AddInformationController`. In this `mainViewController` I have two `UIContainerView`. Each of them embed with a `UITableViewController`. The table view controllers are named `InformationSegmentController` and `ResultSegmentController`.

I put this in `AddInformationController`:

```
InformationSegmentController *isc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentfier:@"InformationSegmentController"];
ResultSegmentController *rsc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ResultSegmentController"];
[self addChildViewController: isc];
[self addChildViewController: rsc];
```

In either the `InformationSegmentController` class or `ResultSegmentController` class, I tried to Log this:
`NSLog(@"%@",self.parentViewController);`
But unfortunately, it is a nil. How can I get the parentViewController correctly? Do I have to use the `prepareForSegue`?

// Question Update:

I found that I don't have to call `addChildViewController` method again if I create those childViewControllers directly in my storyboard.

I have tried to `NSLog(@"%@", self.childViewControllers)` in my `AddInformationController` and the result contains `InformationSegmentController` class and `ResultSegmentController` class.

But the problem is when I call `NSLog(@"%@", self.parentViewController)` on both childViewContorllers in `viewDidLoad`, the results is nil.

Comment: Obviously it all depends on _when_ you do that logging and _who_ is `self`. Perhaps the `self` here is not the same instance you added as a child.

Comment: I have put the `NSLog(@"%@", self.parentViewController)` in the `viewDidLoad` method in the InformationSegmentController class

Comment: Now I understand. The childViewController's viewDidLoad calls earlier than the parentViewController. So I probably NSLog it before the parentViewController even add the childViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try like this

```
//add childview
    [self addChildViewController:aVC];
    [self.view addSubview:aVC.view];
    [aVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    //remove
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
    [self didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Hope it Helps you.

**OR**
another way to get `PerentViewController` in `ChildViewControler` is Make  `@property (strong, nonatomic) AddInformationController *ParentVC;` in Your `ChildViewController.h` and assign `viewController` from your `ParentViewController` Like

```
InformationSegmentController *isc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentfier:@"InformationSegmentController"];
isc.ParentVC = self;
[self addChildViewController: isc];
```

Comment: If you put `@property (strong, nonatomic) AddInformationController * ParentVC` in the InformationSegmentController.h inside the interface, when you compile it, there will be an error saying that `Unknown Type name AddInformationController`. I'm 101% sure I have import that header.

Comment: And I found out that this is much more about the circular issue. Since the childViewController must load before the parentViewController, if you try to import the parentViewController in the childViewController, the childViewController doesn't know what is parentViewController because it doesn't not exist yet. So I just use `@class` instead of `#import` and the problem was fixed.

Comment: as per my understanding this is Cycle issue of viewController, but also you have imported Properly. may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897268/xcode-unknown-type-name  **OR**  try to replace `(weak, nonatomic)` . also i will find another way for you.

Comment: No no no, the cycle issue was already fixed :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Give identifiers to both the segues to your container views(suppose "InformationSegmentControllerSegue" and "ResultSegmentControllerSegue" ,namely) and use prepareForSegue in your AddInformationController like this:

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"InformationSegmentControllerSegue"]) {
            InformationSegmentController *container1 = segue.destinationViewController;
        }
else if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ResultSegmentControllerSegue"]) {
            ResultSegmentController *container2 = segue.destinationViewController;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you.