# Create new class instance from within another instance method (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, instance

I am (essentially) new to programming and attempting to learn Objective-C. I am working on a unit conversion program that uses an instance of a class to store and convert a unit. So for example, if I would like to convert 1 ft to inches, the program does the following:

1. Create a new instance of Length class (myLength)
2. Store the value and unit in a new instance of the class (myMass)
3. Call an instance method to convert the value to new units

My Length class is working fine and just as I expect.

Now I would like to create a new class called Area that creates two instances of the Length class, and uses the Length class to perform the conversions. However, when I attempt to declare a new instance of my Length class from within Area.m, I get the warning "Length undeclared".

Is it possible to create an instance of a different class from within an instance method? More specifically, can I create two instances of my Length class from within the Area class instance method?

(Please forgive me in advance if I have botched any of my terminology).

Here's a snippet of the code in Area.m that is giving me trouble:

```
@implementation Area

-(void) setCompound: (double) myVal unit1: (char) c1 unit2: (char) c2

{

// Create two new instances of the Length class
// THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES ARE GIVING ME TROUBLE
Length * aLength = [[Length alloc] init];  
Length * bLength = [[Length alloc] init];

[aLength setLength:myVal units: c1]; // Set the value and units of first length

[bLength setLength: 1 units: c2]; // Set the value and units of the second length

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import your Length header file in Area.h

```
#import "Length.h"
```

Comment: This import should be in Area.m, not Area.h.

Comment: Awesome. Should have thought of that. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Josh I've always imported header files into the header, then imported the corresponding header into the implementation...this is the style taught by the stanford iOS course...(i.e. import length.h into area.h, import area.h into area.m)...is this wrong?

Comment: @Josh Or is it just unnecessary to do it the way I'm talking about since Length isn't exposed in any method signatures?

Comment: The code that's in Area's header (the `@interface`) doesn't need to see Length.h; only Area's `@implementation` does. If you have two classes that need to know about each other, you can't put `#import "TheOtherOne.h"` in both headers -- circular imports make the compiler barf. I find it best (and have heard it recommended) to import headers into .m files.

Comment: If you need to refer to a class in a header, you should use a [forward declaration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF124) `@class Length;` to let the compiler know about the name. At the risk of tooting my own horn -- you could have a look at [my recent answer about circular imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896440/objective-c-header-file-not-recognizing-custom-object-as-a-type/7896496#7896496).