# Unknown type error

Tags: ios, xcode4

In the following code in interface file I get the error "Unknown type name RefreshScreen"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Storekit/Storekit.h>
#import "RefreshScreen.h"

@interface ViewControllerWordHelper : UIViewController <SKProductsRequestDelegate,    SKPaymentTransactionObserver, UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {    

RefreshScreen *rs;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) RefreshScreen * rs;

@end;
```

In the same project I have RefreshScreen class defined RefreshScreen.h and RefreshScreen.m and they have no errors.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try using `@class RefreshScreen` instead of `#import "RefreshScreen.h"`

Comment: and check if you have a circle in your project, meaning that two classes import each other, this confuses the compiler. a great answer to this problem can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896440/objective-c-header-file-not-recognizing-custom-object-as-a-type

Comment: Thanks Sebastian.  Changing it to class fixed the problem.

Comment: i added it as answer so you can mark it as accepted =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
@class RefreshScreen
```

instead of

```
#import "RefreshScreen.h"
```

More on this topic can be found here (about circling imports)

[Objective-C header file not recognizing custom object as a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896440/objective-c-header-file-not-recognizing-custom-object-as-a-type)